# Balance of strength between Asuras and Devas

Tags: gods, indra, asuras, buddhism

Here is an extract from a Buddhist scripture (the Caturdevarājasūtra) that directly connects the balance of strength between the Asuras and the Devas with Humanities morality:

> During the monthly six days of fast, the messenger-princes (dūtakumāra) and the four kings of the gods (caturdevarāja) examine (anuvicaranti) beings. If the people who cultivate generosity, observe morality and honor their parents are few in number (alpaka), they go to the Tao li gods (Trāyastriṃśa) and inform Ti che (Śakra); Śakra and the gods are unhappy (anāttamanas) and say: “Surely **the armies of the asuras are increasing and the armies of the devas are decreasing**.” If the people who cultivate generosity, observe morality and honor their parents are many (bahu), the gods and Śakra are happy and say: “**The armies of the devas are increasing and the armies of the asuras are decreasing**.”
>   [source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/buddhism/book/maha-prajnaparamita-sastra/d/doc225322.html)

Note: Śakra=Indra

Now I was wondering if there are any Hindu scriptures connoting the same idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I was wondering if there are any Hindu scriptures connoting the same idea?

**Yes, the strength of the various good and evil forces depends on the most predominant Guna in the universe.**

From the *Srimad Bhagavatam*:

> [**7.1.8**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/7/1/): When the quality of goodness [satta] is prominent, the sages [Rishis] and
>   demigods [Devas] flourish with the help of that quality, with which they are
>   infused and surcharged by the Supreme Lord. Similarly, when the mode
>   of passion [rajas] is prominent the demons [Asuras] flourish, and when ignorance [tamas] is
>   prominent the Yakṣas and Rākṣasas flourish. The Supreme Personality of
>   Godhead is present in everyone’s heart, fostering the reactions of
>   sattva-guṇa, rajo-guṇa and tamo-guṇa.
>
> **[11.25.19](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/25/)** - With the increase of the mode of goodness, the strength of the demigods [Devas] similarly increases. When passion increases, the demoniac [Asuras]
>   become strong. And with the rise of ignorance, O Uddhava, the strength
>   of the most wicked [Rakshasas] increases.

Comment: Good find! Interesting subdivision between Sattva, Rajas and Tamas. Do you know of more Puranic references?

Comment: @GabeHiemstra Thanks. I just added Srimad Bhagavatam 11.25.19 to the answer. I'll try to find more and add them.

Comment: @GabeHiemstra If I've answered your question to your satisfaction, could you accept this answer please?